# how do I add css styling to javascript generated HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript that generates HTML like this:

```
function showdropdown(name1,sel, param){
        var dval="";
        dval = "<select name=\"" + name1 + "\" id=\"" + name1 + "\" >";
        dval += "<option value=\"\">Option</option>\r\n";';
```

How do I add a *class="my_style"*  to this? It must be super-easy but unfortunately I don't know anything about javascript structure combined with HTML.

I tried this:

```
        dval = "<select name=\"" + name1 + "\" id=\"" + name1 + "\" class=\""mystyle"\">";
```

which didn't work :(

Comment: You seem to know how to do string concatenation. Why do you think adding the class is any different from adding the name or id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure from the information in your post, but I'm guessing your `mystyle` variable doesn't reference anything. You may be looking for something like…

```
dval = "<select name=\"" + name1 + "\" id=\"" + name1 + "\" class=\"my_style\">";
```

What you are doing (i.e. creating a string representation of the markup) should work as long as you work out any syntax errors you create and such. But this is often the problem with your approach: it easily leads to errors, especially as the HTML becomes increasingly complex.

You may want to consider using the available DOM methods to create and work with elements.

e.g.

```
var divElement = document.createElement('div');
divElement.id = 'some-id'; // Add an ID attribute
divElement.className = 'error'; // Set (and replace any existing) class attribute
divElement.classList.add('bordered'); // Another method of adding a class (no replace)
divElement.textContent = 'Hello, hello!'; // Set the text content… it's all good
document.body.appendChild(divElement); // Append the node to the document
```

You can check out this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wp4Lwz9f/) to see it in action. And if you would like more information on available DOM methods, you can check out [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) and [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) documentation.

*To comment on @Seano666's answer… he's right that using the two styles of quotes can make things easier than escaping. But you should use outer single quotes, and use double quotes for the HTML as a matter of standard.*

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the most detailed answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You really should use quotes/ticks for stuff like this, it's much easier than escaping quotes.

Also, you didn't use the plus operators on mystyle

```
 dval = "<select name='" + name1 + "' id='" + name1 + "' class='" + mystyle + "'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to add class `my_style` or `mystyle`? If you wanted `my_style` you are missing an underscore.

No need to add double quotes if the class name is not a variable:

```
dval = "<select name=\"" + name1 + "\" id=\"" + name1 + "\" class=\"mystyle\">";
```